# Not able to deploy kie workbench 6.4 war file

Tags: jboss7.x, kie, kie-workbench

When I am starting the JBoss server with kie workench 6.4 war file, I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: social-files/<system>
```

Comment: What is your operating system? 
Is JBoss server Wildfly? And did you have a previously installed version of the workbench?

Comment: Hi,
My system is windows 64bit. Server wildfly8.2.0
With wildfly8.2.0 drools 6.3 war file is getting deployed and working fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since your system is Windows and you are using Wildfly this might be caused by a CDI bug that the combination introduces. I recommend you either change the operating system or try another container for the war.